# Is it Mutar to Listen to Music Recorded in a Church?

Tags: halacha, avodah-zarah, christianity, music, hanaah-benefit

I read somewhere that listening to music recorded in a church is asur, because it essentially brings the church into one's home. This is common practice for classical music. Has anyone heard of or not heard of this? Does anyone know a source?

Comment: Welcome Dovid and thanks for the question. You say that it  is common practice to record classical music in a church. Do you want to distinguish between explictily religious music (say a requiem) and other music (say Saint-Saëns's Carnival of the Animals)?

Comment: Classical music maybe was composed for the church but what makes you say it is recorded in a church? Maybe in an orchestral theatre? Or in a music studio

Comment: Thanks! For the sake of simplicity, I'm referring to secular music. Plenty of Bach and other baroque composers are recorded in churches by some of my favorite ensembles, such as Voices of Music. I have separate thread a couple before this one on listening to Christian music in general, which I'm hoping will get some answers.

Comment: @Dovid I've always assumed Bach is worse since he dedicated every single piece he wrote to Jesus.
Johann carefully formed the letters J J at the top of the page. With that, the music began to pour from his soul and onto the page. When he was finally satisfied, he wrote the letters SDG at the bottom of the page - Soli Deo Gloria - For the Glory of God Alone. He hoped that when the music was played, it would point toward God.
https://www.google.com/amp/s/www.christianity.com/wiki/people/j-s-bach-soli-deo-gloria-to-the-glory-of-god-alone-11635057.html%3famp=1

Answer (score 1):

The following Rabbanim address this question and allow it

- Rabbi Yuval Sherlo - [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20210616224828/http://shut.moreshet.co.il/shut2.asp?id=176328)
- Rabbi Dov Lior - [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20220915000000*/https://www.yeshiva.org.il/ask/6949)

Comment: Could you describe what it says in the two links you mentioned for in case a link gets broken....